# Package Parsing Error In Android at the Time of Installing the Apps in Device

Tags: android

i developed a App name "MyMelody" and give the packgae name "com.mymelody" i developed that app and when i install this app the device give me Package Parsing Error . Please Help me
Thanks and Regards
RizN81

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you change your package name to com.mymelody1 and try it(keep the back up of the old one). Then check it. *if it is not helpful to you, then in the manifest.xml , you check the "uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion= 4" Some times your device version is 2.1 and you have given it as 2.2. Try it and let me know any improvement